# isanswered:0 in searches returns both questions and answers, and answers include either wiki or non-wiki accepted or positively scored answers

Tags: bug, search

From [How do I search? - Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching):

> isanswered: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one accepted or positively-scored answer; **no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted or positively-scored answers.**

But the `isanswered:0` operator [returns both questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+ubuntu).

Assuming that this is the intended behavior (altough I'd find it weird regardless) the problem might just be with the description within the Help Center, which should have been [...] **only questions or answers to questions** [...].

But it also [returns both wiki and non-wiki answers accepted or positively scored](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=isanswered%3a0%20ubuntu) ([third result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed/310#310)).

Either I'm missing something or this is not the intended behavior.

---

**EDIT**: [this has now partially been fixed by changing the description in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277661/302251), but the operator still [returns both questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=isanswered%3A0+ubuntu).

---

**EDIT 2**: [this has now been fixed completely by implying `is:question` when searching using `isanswered:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277674/302251).